# Highcharts buttons

Tags: javascript, highcharts

does any one know if it is possible to include a button inside of highcharts? I have a bar chart and I want to put a button on the left of the label somthing like this  [bar chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic)  but with a button before Africa, America, Asia etc.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not support by highchart. You may use javascript to hack it, e.g. find the node *$(.highcharts-axis)* and add the button for each child.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah it's not possible. I ended up fixing the bar height and adding html buttons to the left of the bars... was quite complicated to get the exact height as the chart changed across multiple browsers but in the end it did the trick. Thanks!